# Swift - How to create line breaks in an array (Displayed in a UILabel)

Tags: ios, arrays, xcode, swift

I'm trying to create an app that displays random famous historical quotes. I use a UIlabel to display quotes from an array randomly.
However with long quotes, they look like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5j7at.png

Here's the code:

`var quoteArray: [String] = [
    "We are not makers of history, we are made by history - Martin Luther King Jr",
    "Without education you're not going anywhere in this world - Malcolm X"]`

So i select randomly from this array, but i can't find a way to create line breaks (so the whole quote can be seen) without disrupting the code. 
Any idea how to do it?

Should i change from a UILabel to something else? 
or is there a way to add line breaks

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

Set the number of lines of your label to `0` and to line breaks to "Word Wrap".

Comment: Genius. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

To do a line break, you type `"\r\n"` so in your case, I recommend saying:

`var quoteArray: [String] = ["We are not makers of history, we are made by history - Martin Luther King Jr", "\r\n", "Without education you're not going anywhere in this world - Malcolm X"]`